# 3 Factor Mixed Model ANOVA in SPSS

Tags: spss, interaction, anova

I would like to know if I am choosing the right test.

Goal: Does the typing speed (dependent variable) differ between two types of keyboards.

Dependent Variable: Typing Speed.

Independent variables:

- Keyboard: KB1, KB2 [Between factor variable]
- Keysize: Small, Large [within factor varabile]
- KeyShape: Square, Circle [within factor varabile]

I have two group of users, Group1 tests Keyboard_1 (KB1)
Group2 tests keyboard_2 (KB2).

So, from my perspective, this is a 3 factor mixed model ANOVA.

2(keyboard) x 2 (keysize) x 2(keyshape)

To perform this analysis in SPSS, I'm choosing Analyze -> General Linear Model -> Repeated Measures.

1. Is my understanding right?
2. How to interpret the significance of a factor.
   For example, if  "keysize" factor has P < 0.05 (significant), does it mean that the typing speed (IV) differs based on the keysize alone (small vs large) and not considering the other factors.
3. How to interpret the interactions?
   If interaction  Keysize * Keyboard is not significant. Does it mean that multiple levels of keysize (small or large) do not cross lines (typing speed) for the multiple levels of the keyboard ( x axis - KB1, KB2).
   Also, in an interaction like A * B * C, is the last factor (C) always on the X axis?